# Add subordinate directives?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

So I want to be able to author an element like so:

```
<div my-directive></div>
```

And, I'd like `my-directive` to add subordinate directives.

```
<div my-directive subordinate-directive></div>
```

Currently, I'm adding these directives at compile time, but they don't get re-run. On children elements generated from the directive's template, I can do whatever I wish, because I'm likely adding to the child template before directives run.

Example:
http://plnkr.co/edit/6y6Ebzqf1gLkTBEUcKfi?p=preview

Comment: could you provide a plunker, it might be easier to help

Comment: "they don't get re-run on a parent element" -- I'm not following you here.  Can you explain a bit more?

Comment: I am going to be a bit pedantic here. That isnt a "subordinate-directive". That would be a "sibling-directive". I cant see a reason why you would want to insert a sibling-directive from another directive. I am sure that in almost all cases where you are trying to insert a directive from another directive ( and then compiling it ) you will be able to do it either in the template or dont need to do it at all ( i.e you can refactor this to be better ).

Comment: I'll plunker it in a sec. @ganaraj, I'm having other people author templates in a simple language. I'd like to automatically apply other directives when they do other directives... so for instance if they do `queue`, that automatically gets `trim-whitespace` and other related directives.

Comment: @RandallB the more specific your example, the better. Will have a look at your plunkr once you provide it. Meanwhile, I think 'trim-whitespace'  ( assuming its functionality from the name ! ) seems to fall more into the 'filter' category than a directive.

Comment: Added example. @ganaraj, I get what you're saying, but I don't want to have to explain piping to my template writing css/html n00bs. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that by the time **my-directive** is being processed the **collect directives** phase has passed and modifying the element won't trigger a new compile.

You need to manually trigger the compile phase again after you added all the other directives, see [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/ix7wmdlSVrwXlC6x0KWI?p=preview).

```
app.directive("queue", [ '$compile', function($compile) {
  var directiveDefinitionObject;
    directiveDefinitionObject = {
      scope: {},
      controller: [
        '$scope', function($scope) {
          $scope.entries = [{name: 1}, {name: 2}, {name: 3}];
        }
      ],
      template: $("#entry").html(),
      compile : function(tElement, tAttrs, transclude) {
        var compiler;

        //All children related directives go here since the template hasn't been
        //appended yet in the post link function when we re-compile
        tElement.children().attr('ng-repeat', 'entry in entries');

        compiler = {
          pre : function(scope, iElement, iAttrs, controller) {
          },
          post : function(scope, iElement, iAttrs, controller) {
            if (iElement.attr('can-do-thing-i-define') === undefined) {
              var c = tElement.clone();

              c.attr('can-do-thing-i-define', '');

              $compile(c)(scope);

              iElement.replaceWith(c);
            }
          }
        };
        return compiler;
      }
    };
    return directiveDefinitionObject;
}]);
```